# Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1 - Product Gallery Image cannot upload; Error : Something went wrong while saving the file(s)

Tags: magento2, image-upload, media, media-images

I cannot upload images for new products or existing ones. All will show the error screenshot below.

[image]

Also, when I check on DevTools the data-URL showing as below.

[image]

This problem only happens when I upload images on a new product or edit an existing product.

I have tried the methods below:

1. Change the pub/media folder permission.
2. https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Error-Something-went-wrong-while-savin...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your logs it will show some error while uploading if yes can you post it with question ?